# How can I create a query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django model that includes two related models: "RunningTasks" and "PointsforUser". I am attempting to create a new task for a user and set the task's point value equal to the user's current point balance. However, I'm not sure how to do this with the given model.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
class PointsforUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)

class RunningTasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    fixed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RunningTasks
        fields = ('task',)

class RunTaskCreateUserView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):    
    model = RunningTasks
    template_name = 'usersboard/tasks_create.html'
    form_class = TaskCreateForm       
   
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class Task(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, unique=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField( max_length=500)
    theme = TreeForeignKey('Theme', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='tasks', null=True)
    url = models.CharField( max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, default=10)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default='in job', verbose_name='Статус', max_length=10)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    points = models.CharField( null=True, default=1)
    fixed = models.BooleanField( default=False)
```

How can I set a user's point value as the default point value for a task?

I create

```py
task = Task.objects.filter(points__lt=PointsforUser.objects.filter(points=F("points")))
```

But I get this error:

> MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one PointsforUser

It returned 2 objects. How can I send id authorized user in query?

Comment: where is your Task model?

Comment: sorry. I add Task model

Comment: in your models, there is no connection between `Task` and `PointsforUser`.In fact, your Task has no owner! you should first make a direct connection between them via add `ForeignKey` to `PointsforUser` or an indirect connection via `ForeignKey` to `User` in the `Task` model. then you can get related points.

Comment: And can you suggest an approximate implementation? I thought I should make a filter for the task field in TaskCreateForm, but I ran into the problem of inserting the id of an authorized user.

Comment: And another nuance, the user should only be visible tasks that match the sum of his points

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, it seems you are looking for something like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) # add relation to user
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, unique=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField( max_length=500)
    theme = TreeForeignKey('Theme', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='tasks', null=True)
    url = models.CharField( max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, default=10)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default='in job', verbose_name='Статус', max_length=10)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    points = models.CharField( null=True, default=1)
    fixed = models.BooleanField( default=False)
    
    # set PointsforUser.points as default value of Task.points
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        points_for_user = PointsforUser.objects.get(user=self.user)
        self.points = points_for_user.points
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sorry, and what does SubProductOptions refer to?

Comment: Ops, sorry it comes from my clipboard :/ check edited version